# MySQL bigint number - different output in SQL and R

Tags: mysql, r

I have stored a value as varchar and as bigint in a MySQL DB:
`userID_as_varchar` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`userID_as_bigint` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,

```
+--------------------+---------------------------+
| userID_as_varchar  | userID_as_bigint          |
+--------------------+---------------------------+
| 917876131364446205 |        917876131364446200 |
+--------------------+---------------------------+
```

For any reason, I can't query the full userID_as_bigint value in full precision with SQL, but with R.

Behaviour SQL:
If I query the data or cast it it's always the "rounded" value.
Tested in phpMyAdmin and directly with sql command in shell.

Behaviour R:
If I query the field with R (RMySQL package) the value is complete 917876131364446205

Can anyone explain this behaviour or know a way how to get the full value with SQL.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you mean, here's a test:

```
create table test(t1 varchar(50), t2 bigint);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> desc test
    -> ;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| t1    | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| t2    | bigint(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into test values('917876131364446205', 917876131364446205);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from test;
+--------------------+--------------------+
| t1                 | t2                 |
+--------------------+--------------------+
| 917876131364446205 | 917876131364446205 |
+--------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```